# ProfilePropertyService.svc fails with InvalidOperationException

Tags: 2010, user-profile

Does anyone know how to provision the UPA so that the ProfilePropertyService.svc actually works? I am getting the error below in all our environments if I try to access the service directly from a browser using the following URL:

```
http://server:32843/ccdeac1e731c4b00b0b3f79e425b9d04/ProfilePropertyService.svc
```

I have tried to drop the UPA and provision it again from the ground up using the [Scripts from Spencer Harbars SharePoint Conference Sessions](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2011/10/16/339.aspx). Everything works fine except the ProfilePropertyService.

The error is currently causing one WFE in our farm to fail when trying to access the UPA through the UPA Proxy. The farm has 2xWFE in one domain and 1xApp server in another. The first WFE is fine but the second one fails with a NullReferenceException in the UserProfileApplicationProxy class. I have in the ULS traced this back to the error from the UserProfileService.svc. It is quite a mystery why one WFE can access the UPA and the other not! It is for sure not a firewall issue between the two domains as the service error also shows when I try to access the service from the App. server itself.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension.
Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement
Error: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider. Policy export for such a binding is not supported. Make sure the transport binding element in the binding implements the ITransportTokenAssertionProvider interface. ----> System.InvalidOperationException: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider. Policy export for such a binding is not supported. Make sure the transport binding element in the binding implements the ITransportTokenAssertionProvider interface.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement.System.ServiceModel.Description.IPolicyExportExtension.ExportPolicy(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext policyContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExporter.ExportPolicy(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

UPDATE:
We are also seeing the following related errors in the logs on the WFE server:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalAvailable()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.EnsureMySiteUrls()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.get_PortalMySiteUrlAvailable()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.MyLinksRibbon.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Exception occured while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.     -
-- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:     
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown
 at [0]:     
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfilePropertyService.GetProfileProperties()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetProfileProperties>b__0(IProfilePropertyService channel)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
```

Comment: The problem seems to have resolved itself after a weeks time! That is, our second WFE is now able to access user profiles again. But the ProfilePropertyService.svc is still responding with the same error. Any ideas how this can happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it myself now! It turned out that the interal clock on the WFE server was about 10 minutes ahead of the clock on the Application server hosting the User Profile Application. WCF does not accept this difference in time between the servers and responds with the error *An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party*.